# Enable/disable range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a range input which is defined this way:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.Quality, Resources.CompressionQuality)
<input type="range" name="Quality" id="Quality" data-mini="true" min="0" max="100" value="@Model.Quality">
```

and a dropdown:

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => Model.TiffCompression, Resources.TiffCompression)
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.TiffCompression, tiffCompressions, Html.DataMiniAttribute())
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.TiffCompression)
```

Depending on the DropDown selection I want to enable/disable the range input. Here is how I do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function ToggleSection() {
            var selectedVal = $('#TiffCompression').find('option:selected').val();
            $('#Quality').prop('disabled', true);

            switch (selectedVal) {
                case "JPEG":
                    $('#Quality').prop('disabled', false);
                    break;
            }
        }

        ToggleSection();
        $('#TiffCompression').change(function () { ToggleSection(); });
    });
</script>
```

The disabled property is really changed, but the control is not refreshed until I click on it. I've tried to call `change()`, different refreshes etc. on it but no luck.

How can I enable/disable it?

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, the range input changes immediately, even when focus is on the drop down and I use the up and down arrow keys.  Are you sure you are not receiving any javascript errors?  I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 and Chrome 29.0.1547.62.

Comment: Just tried Firefox 23.0.1 and Internet Explorer 10 and it works in both of those as well.

Comment: @asymptoticFault $('#Quality').slider("enable") did the job, thanks for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why it didn't work, but

```
$('#Quality').slider('disable');
```

and

```
$('#Quality').slider("enable");
```

did the job.